# React Native Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native

tryingn to use api call to render listview

```
    (rowData)=><CatalogCell newWidth={imgWidth} imgMargin = 
    {imgMargin} 
    url={rowData.product.name} price={rowData.price}/>
```

i can read the price properly, but if i read anything beyond depth 1, i got this error, basiclly rowData.product wont give me anything, but if i go rowData.product, it will show error

got

```
Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

renderRow
    CatalogList.js:74:114
StaticRenderer.render
    StaticRenderer.js:32:22
<unknown>
    ReactCompositeComponent.js:1218:19
measureLifeCyclePerf
    ReactCompositeComponent.js:63:11
ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext
    ReactCompositeComponent.js:1217:24
ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent
    ReactCompositeComponent.js:1249:31
ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount
    ReactCompositeComponent.js:499:29
ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent
    ReactCompositeComponent.js:346:20
Object.mountComponent
    ReactReconciler.js:56:34
Constructor.mountChildren
    ReactMultiChild.js:276:41
```

code to set listview data:

```
componentDidMount(){
        getCatalog((callback)=>{
            console.warn(callback.result.data)
            this.setState({
                dataSource:this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(
                   callback.result.data
               ),
                loading:false,
            })
        })
    }
```

Comment: can you console.log and show me what is the data that rowdata gets and also can you show me how are you setting the value rowData

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, should have a flag telling if the data is ready. depth 1 works because props is always there